# Cross platform recurring app subscriptions

Tags: android, ios, subscription, recurring, in-app

I have been researching this topic for several days now and I have not found a conclusive answer.

I am working on an event sharing app that uses cloud storage. I want to charge users a recurring monthly subscription for the storage. There will be an Android, iOS and web version of this app. For the iOS and Android components I would like the subscriptions to be managed through the iTunes/Google Play. For the web component I will use some other form of payment like Paypal.

So my questions for this are:

Will Apple reject the app if the user can sign up for the subscription somewhere besides the iOS app?

If this is allowed, how can I tell if the user has an active subscription cross-platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this for my mobile dating apps. I have an iOS version and an Android version with a recurring subscription for premium service. I store the time the subscription expires in a database column in my users table, and send that down to the app when the app syncs with the server. If the time is greater than now, the user is considered a premium user.

Although I actually don't have any real subscriptions from users for my apps, this should work.

Other dating apps (and other apps, I'm pretty sure) that are cross platform already do this (Zoosk is one example) as far as I know so I don't think you'll have a problem from Apple.

This should work with a web app as well, using the same technique.

Edit: To get subscription expiry time:

Send the receipt data to your server.  I use this PHP library for verifying receipt data: https://github.com/aporat/store-receipt-validator. After checking if the receipt is valid, you can get the expiration date in ms from the response of aporat lib.

Comment: Thank you! It actually looks like Evernote does this as well. My only other question is how do you know when the subscription ends if it is a recurring subscription?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include that info. Be sure to accept it if the answer works for you.